# Django slug url in perisan 404

Tags: python, django, django-urls, slug

I have a django url:

```
path('question/<slug:question_slug>/add_vote/', views.AddVoteQuestionView.as_view())
```

It work fine with english slug but when slug is persian something like this:

`/question/سوال-تست/add_vote/`

django url throw `404 Not Found`, is there any solution to catch this perisan slug url?

**EDIT:**

I'm using django 2.1.5.

It work fine with this url:

```
re_path(r'question/(?P<question_slug>[\w-]+)/add_vote/$', views.AddVoteQuestionView.as_view())
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an addition to [Selcuk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2011147/selcuk) answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55175589/8283848)

---

to pass such language/unicode characters you have to

1. [Write some custom path converter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#registering-custom-path-converters)
2. Use [**`re_path()`** function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path)

   ---

#### 1 . Custom path converter

If we look into the source code of Django, the [**`slug`**](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/urls/converters.py#L35) path converter uses this regex,
 **`[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+`** which is inefficent here (see Selcuk's answer).
So, Write your own custom slug converter , as below

```
from django.urls.converters import SlugConverter


class CustomSlugConverter(SlugConverter):
    regex = '[-\w]+' # new regex pattern
```

Then register it,

```
from django.urls import path, register_converter

register_converter(CustomSlugConverter, 'custom_slug')

urlpatterns = [
    path('question/<custom_slug:question_slug>/add_vote/', views.AddVoteQuestionView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

#### 2. using [**`re_path()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urls/#re-path)

You've already tried and succeeded with this method. Anyway, I'm c&p it here :)

```
from django.urls import re_path

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'question/(?P<question_slug>[\w-]+)/add_vote/$', views.AddVoteQuestionView.as_view()),
    ...
]
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Django 2.1 documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/http/urls/#path-converters) you can only use ASCII letters or numbers for `slug` patterns:

> `slug` - Matches any slug string consisting of ASCII letters or numbers, plus the hyphen and underscore characters. For example, `building-your-1st-django-site`.

whereas regex `\w` pattern also matches Unicode word characters:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#index-32

> For Unicode (str) patterns:
>   Matches Unicode word characters; this includes most characters that can be part of a word in any language, as well as numbers and the underscore. If the ASCII flag is used, only `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` is matched.